# Razorpay says No key passed when trying to create instance

Tags: reactjs, firebase, nuxt.js, payment-gateway, razorpay

I am trying to integrate Razorpay with my Nuxt App. And everything is fine when I run it in **test mode**. I don't know why but it does not require **order_id** in test mode.
But when I tried to add **order_id** field for doing payment in **live mode**. The below code is required first for Initialization of Razorpay.

Note - Got this from Razorpay Docs https://razorpay.com/docs/api/orders/#create-an-order

```
var instance = new Razorpay({
  key_id: 'YOUR_KEY_ID', //I added my live mode key_id here.
  key_secret: 'YOUR_KEY_SECRET' ////I added my live mode key_secret here.
})
```

And to create order, this code is given.

```
instance.orders.create({amount, currency, receipt, notes})
```

I wrote the code in methods and console.log(instance) to see what is coming in it. But as soon as I pressed the button to run the function. It gave me error **No key passed**. Even though my keys are correct. Here is my code.

```
 pay() {
          var instance = new Razorpay({
            key_id: 'my_actual_key_id',
            key_secret: 'my_actual_key_secret',
          })
          console.log('Ins', instance)
          var options = {
            amount: 1000,  
            currency: "INR",
            receipt: "order_rcptid_11"
           };
          instance.orders.create(options, function(err, order) {
           console.log(order);
             });
       },
```

I don't know why it is giving **No key passed error**.
Is there a mistake in my code?
I cannot find any other way to get order_id. Also unable to find any answer or video that is creating order_id, through this method.

Answer (score 1):

Try `key` instead of `key_id`. That should work.

Comment: Thank You for answering. But the code is working as it should be. Key_id is correct.